# How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my android application?

Tags: android, background-process

I'm developing an android application which requires *background updates of my location*.

I don't know how I can run my app running on background.

Comment: I know how to fetch location details such has latitude and longitude.. but i am struggling with how to run it in background after certain time duration .. i dont have any clue how that will work. @Nik....

Comment: From android documentation "What is a Service": A facility for the application to tell the system about something it wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not directly interacting with the application). You need to read about it in the link below and that should solve your problem!

Comment: But my Problem is different. I am periodically fetching Location details in SERVICE class, but Service class is not supporting Thread or Timer.

Comment: can you suggest me the alternate solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Service class, how it works and documentation can be found here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

The service is like an Activity but with no UI and it can be run in the background even when the user is using other applications.

Regards
Tobias